# How to setup mixed authentication for Web API application (.net framework 4.7)?

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, webapi

I need to add additional authentication method to the existing Web API application that already has the Windows authentication. I have added a Startup file with the code:

```
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TodoList_Web.Startup))]
namespace TodoList_Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    },
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Windows authentication is turned on IIS level and it seems that I should turn of it in IIS and add on the application level - add the configuration to the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>     
       <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
```

Will it work at all? Can I somehow use an Authorize attribute to specify what authentication should be applied to particular method/controller? Something like this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationType=Windows)] 
or 
[Authorize(AuthenticationType=WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearer)]
```

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Answer (score 0):

As no authentication middleware is configured to automatically run and create an identity you must, at the point of authorization choose which middleware will be used.

For .net framework, you could use `authorization policy` to select the middleware you wish to authorize.

An authorization policy is made up of one or more requirements and registered at application startup as part of the Authorization service configuration, in `Configuration` in the `Startup.cs` file.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AbleToCreateUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Manager"));
        });
    }
```

Policies are applied using the `Authorize` attribute **by specifying the policy name**, for example;

```
public class UserManagementController : ApiController 
{
    [ResourceAuthorize(Policy = "AbleToCreateUser")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateUser()
    {
    }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://vladimirgeorgiev.com/blog/policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-4/).

Comment: It seems that you refered article (and whole site) is about .net core framework, isn't it?

Comment: I have update the article and you could refer to it.

Comment: Will it work with together with windows authentication? Can I have one method with [ResourceAuthorize(Policy = "AppliationRole")] attribute secured by AzureActiveDirectory authentication and have another one method with [Authorize] attribute secured with windows authentication?